# Using the correct mySQL ODBC driver in windows

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc

I am trying to connect MS Access with a local mySQL database.
To do this I downloaded the mySQL ODBC connector from the mySQL website and installed it. As I am on a 64-bit system I went for the 64-bit version.

I then discovered when trying to connect Access to mySQL that my installation of Office is actually 32-bit so the driver doesn't work. So I removed the 64-bit ODBC driver and installed the 32-bit one.

Problem is, when I go into `control-panel -> Administrative Tools -> Data Sources (ODBC)` and try to add a new data source, the only options for the mySQL drivers seem to point to the old directory where the 64-bit drivers were. It then fails as it can't find the dlls with system error 126.

How do I get it to show the 32-bit drivers?

Comment: Hope this would be helpful: http://www.getdowntonight.co.uk/2009/11/installing-myodbc-3-51-on-windows-7-x64/

Comment: That is indeed very helpful. Might be worth a copy/paste as answer in case anyone else stumbles accross this issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run the 32-bit manager by running this command:

```
c:\windows\syswow64\odbcad32.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use RegisterDatabase() function to create connection from your code.

I wrote wrapper function many years ago: 
http://5codelines.net/kak-programmno-sozdat-odbc-dsn/.
Just skip russian language and use the code.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to installing the ODBC MySQL driver 5.2.6 you need to install the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package for x64 or x86 or both (just search the Microsoft site for these and download from there). Other driver versions may require different versions of this MS VC++ Redist. Package, which can coexist side by side. By default server 2008 R2 comes with the 2008 version, so installing the 2010 is required. Before installing check in Programs and Features if not already installed. Depending on you application it may require the 32 bit or the 64 bit version. Without it you get the system error 126

Then install the drivers:
To install the 32 bit version run as administrator c:\windows\syswow64\odbcad32.exe which is the 32 bit version of "Data Sources (ODBC)"